# c# hook - counting keystrokes on the keyboard

Tags: c#, hook

Statistical program. Not a keyllogger. For me, to know how much of my life I waste by tapping without meaning into the keyboard;}}

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace StatisticChar
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private GlobalKeyboardHook _globalKeyboardHook;

        public void SetupKeyboardHooks()
        {
            _globalKeyboardHook = new GlobalKeyboardHook();
            _globalKeyboardHook.KeyboardPressed += OnKeyPressed;
        }
        private void OnKeyPressed(object sender, GlobalKeyboardHookEventArgs e)
        {


            if (e.KeyboardState == GlobalKeyboardHook.KeyboardState.KeyDown)
            {
                var znak = $"{(char)e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode} {e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode}";


                //////////////////////    SEKCJA F1   ///////////////////////////////////////////
                if ((e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode >= 112) && (e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode <= 123))
                {
                    znak = "F" + (e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode - 111).ToString();
                }

                //////////////////////   SEKCJA NUMERYCZNA ///////////////////////////////////////////

                if ((e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode >= 96) && (e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode <= 105))
                {
                    znak = (e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode - 96).ToString();
                }


                if (e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode == 144)
                {
                    znak = "NumLock";
                }

                if (e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode == 111)
                {
                    znak = "/";
                }

                if (e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode == 106)
                {
                    znak = "*";
                }

                if (e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode == 109)
                {
                    znak = "-";
                }

                if (e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode == 107)
                {
                    znak = "+";
                }

                if (e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode == 107)
                {
                    znak = ",";
                }

                //////////////////////   SEKCJA GŁÓWNA ///////////////////////////////////////////

                if (e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode == 13)
                {
                    znak = "ENTER";
                }

                if (e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode == 192)
                {
                    znak = "`";
                }

                if (e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode == 9)
                {
                    znak = "tabulator";
                }

                if (e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode == 20)
                {
                    znak = "capslock";
                }

                if (e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode == 160)
                {
                    znak = "LewyShift";
                }

                if (e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode == 162)
                {
                    znak = "ctrl";
                }

                if (e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode == 91)
                {
                    znak = "win";
                }

                if (e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode == 32)
                {
                    znak = "spacja";
                }

                if (e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode == 37)
                {
                    znak = "←";
                }

                if (e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode == 39)
                {
                    znak = "→";
                }

                if (e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode == 38)
                {
                    znak = "↑";
                }

                if (e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode == 40)
                {
                    znak = "↓";
                }

                if (e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode == 8)
                {
                    znak = "backup";
                }

                if (e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode == 161)
                {
                    znak = "prawyShift";
                }

                if (e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode == 93)
                {
                    znak = "ppm";
                }

                if (e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode == 45)
                {
                    znak = "insert";
                }

                if (e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode == 44)
                {
                    znak = "printscreen";
                }

                if (e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode == 19)
                {
                    znak = "pause";
                }

                if (e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode == 166)
                {
                    znak = "back";
                }

                if (e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode == 36)
                {
                    znak = "home";
                }

                if (e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode == 35)
                {
                    znak = "end";
                }

                if (e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode == 46)
                {
                    znak = "delete";
                }

                if (e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode == 33)
                {
                    znak = "pageUp";
                }

                if (e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode == 34)
                {
                    znak = "pagDown";
                }

                if (e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode == 163)
                {
                    znak = "PrawyCtrl";
                }



                //////////////////////   INNE, POZOSTAŁE ///////////////////////////////////////////

                if (e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode == 1)
                {
                    znak = "LeftClick";
                }

                if (e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode == 2)
                {
                    znak = "RightClick";
                }



                Statystyki[znak] = Statystyki.ContainsKey(znak) ? ++Statystyki[znak] : 1;
            }
        }
        public new void Dispose()
        {
            base.Dispose();
            _globalKeyboardHook?.Dispose();
        }


        private DateTime data_zbierania_statystyk;
        private static readonly Dictionary<string, int> Statystyki = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        public Form1()
        {
            _globalKeyboardHook = new GlobalKeyboardHook();
            SetupKeyboardHooks();

            var dt = DateTime.Now;
            data_zbierania_statystyk = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, dt.Hour, dt.Minute, 0);

            Timer timer = new Timer
            {
                Interval = 1 * 10 * 1000
            };
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Tick);
            timer.Start();

            Timer timer2 = new Timer
            {
                Interval = 1000
            };
            timer2.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer2_Tick);
            timer2.Start();

            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           richTextBox1.Text = StatystykiJakoText();
        }

        void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Saves();
        }
        void Saves()
        {
            var dt = DateTime.Now;
            var now = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, dt.Hour, dt.Minute, 0);

            if (data_zbierania_statystyk < now)
            {
                data_zbierania_statystyk = now;

                string sb = StatystykiJakoText();

                string path = $@"O:\statystyki{dt.Year}-{dt.Month}-{dt.Day}.txt";

                File.AppendAllText(path, sb);

                richTextBox1.Text = "";
                richTextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
            }
        }

        private string StatystykiJakoText()
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
            sb.Append($"Statystyki za dzień: {data_zbierania_statystyk}{Environment.NewLine}");

            foreach (var literka in Statystyki)
            {
                sb.Append($"{literka.Key} - {literka.Value}{Environment.NewLine}");
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }


    }
}
```

However, there is still a problem:

1. I do not catch every character, eg right alt, F Mode
2. Does not catch characters written in some programs, eg Notepad ++?
   Is anyone able to say why this is happening and how to fix it?
3. How to handle shortcuts eg ctrl + c, ctrl + v?
4. How to protect against pressing the key, if we keep it and do not let it go?

Comment: If something in a handler is not captured ... it might have been captured and flagged as "handled" by some other handler ... guessing

Comment: I do not understand? Programming is not my strong point. And I do not currently have the budget to ask for this simple (I think) application for me ... :( I've made the attempt to do it myself, what I present is a few days of fatigue ...

Comment: Good luck then in finishing it.

Comment: Your code need some optimizations - "if (e.KeyboardData.VirtualCode == 35)" - and so on... this is bad coding and too slow. Please change that to switch case. And "if ((int)wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)" is empty. Maybe it's easier to find another solution like keyloggers or anything else...

Answer (score 2):

If you want a full keyboard hook, it will be more interesting to use these functions:

```
public class WindowsHookAPI
{
    //public delegate IntPtr HookDelegate(
    //    Int32 Code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    public delegate IntPtr HookDelegate(Int32 Code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hHook, Int32 nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hHook);


    [DllImport("User32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(Int32 idHook, HookDelegate lpfn, IntPtr hmod, Int32 dwThreadId);
}
```

you are sure to trap all keys and you could easily block some keys if you want..

"its the origin of hook"

you install the global hook like this:

```
keyBoardHandle = WindowsHookAPI.SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, keyBoardDelegate, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
```

and a sample to use it:

```
    private WindowsHookAPI.HookDelegate keyBoardDelegate;
    private IntPtr keyBoardHandle;

    // Hook global keyboard
    private const Int32 WH_KEYBOARD_LL          = 13;
    // flags bits of lParam hookstruct
    private const Int32 LLKHF_EXTENDED          = 0b00000001;
    private const Int32 LLKHF_LOWER_IL_INJECTED = 0b00000010;
    private const Int32 LLKHF_INJECTED          = 0b00010000;
    private const Int32 LLKHF_ALTDOWN           = 0b00100000;
    private const Int32 LLKHF_UP                = 0b10000000;
    // value of wParam
    private const Int32 WM_KEYUP                = 0x0101;
    private const Int32 WM_KEYDOWN              = 0x0100;

    private IntPtr KeyboardHookDelegate(Int32 Code, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {

        hookStruct param = (hookStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(hookStruct));
        if (Code < 0 || (param.flags & LLKHF_INJECTED) != 0)
        {
            return WindowsHookAPI.CallNextHookEx(keyBoardHandle, Code, wParam, lParam);
        }

        if ((int)wParam == WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
         // see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/ns-winuser-tagkbdllhookstruct 
         // for more explanations about type of keys trapped
         // return (IntPtr)1;    // if you want to block some keys
        }

        return WindowsHookAPI.CallNextHookEx(keyBoardHandle, Code, wParam, lParam);
    }

    public struct hookStruct
    {
        public int vkCode;
        public int scanCode;
        public int flags;
        public int time;
        public int dwExtraInfo;
    }
```

to unhook use:

```
WindowsHookAPI.UnhookWindowsHookEx(keyBoardHandle);
```

Comment: if this answer helps you, please, dont forget to uvpvote/validate the answer !!